# Using archiver to zip batch of folders

Tags: javascript, zip

I am trying to zip batch of folders , so I am using archiver

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver
>
> srcpath : contain folder1, folder2, folder3, etc..
>
> destpath : is the path where I should have all my zips

**so my code is :**

```
             fs.readdirSync(srcpath).filter(function (direc) {

                var output = file_system.createWriteStream(destpath + direc + '.zip');
                var archive = archiver('zip');

                output.on('close', function () {
                   console.log(ok);
                });

                archive.on('error', function (err) {
                    throw err;
                });

                archive.pipe(output);
                archive.bulk([
                    {expand: true, cwd:srcpath+direc, src: ['**'], dest: ''}
                ]);
                archive.finalize();


            });
```

> The result of this code is : I have all the zips I need named the right names, in the right destination but Empty!

Can anyone help me please
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This code is already working,
The mistake was in setting the paths
Cheers